# Data lost from input field once there is an error

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title> Register Page </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            session_start();
            $fnameerr = "";
            $lnameerr = "";
            $passworderr = "";
            $emailerr = "";
            $usererr = "";
            $passmatcherr = "";

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                if(empty($_POST['fname'])){
                    $fnameerr = "* Please Enter The First Name";
                }

                if(empty($_POST['lname'])){
                    $lnameerr = "* Please Enter The Last Name";
                }

                if(empty($_POST['username'])){
                    $usererr = "* Please Enter The UserName";
                }

                if(empty($_POST['password'])){
                    $passworderr = "* Please Enter The UserName";
                }

                if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['repassword']){
                    $passmatcherr = "* Password do not match";
                }

                if(empty($_POST['email'])){
                    $emailerr = "* Please Enter the Email Id ";
                }

            }
        ?>
            <h1>Please Fill In The Details</h1><hr>
            <form action="" method=POST >
            <lable> First Name : </lable> <input type=text name = fname placeholder=First Name /><?php echo $fnameerr ?><br><br>
            <lable> Last Name : </lable> <input type=text name = lname  placeholder = Last Name /><?php echo $lnameerr ?><br><br>
            <lable> Username : </lable> <input type=text name = username placeholder=Username /><?php echo $usererr ?><br><br>
            <lable> Password : </lable> <input type=password name = password placeholder=Password /><?php echo $passworderr ?><br><br>
            <lable> Re Password : </lable> <input type=password name = repassword placeholder='Re Password' /><?php echo $passmatcherr ?><br><br>
            <lable> E-Mail Id : </lable> <input type=text name = email placeholder=xyz@hotmail.com /><?php echo $emailerr ?><br><br>
            <lable> Area of Intrest : </lable> <select name=subject >
                                                <option value=maths > Maths </option>
                                                <option value=social > Social </option>
                                                <option value=english > English </option>
                                                <option value=science > Science </option>
                                                </select> <br><br>
            <lable> Want To Be A Instructor </lable> <input type=checkbox /> <br><br>
            <input type = submit name = submit value = Register />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the data to remain in the text field, but the data in all the fields is being lost, what should I do? Actually what I did was, I checked whether all the input fields are set or not and checking the re-typed password matches or not.

Comment: You need to use `$_SESSION` or `$_POST` for this. But `$_POST` will be lost if the page is refreshed.

Comment: And `label` is spelled `label` - also do not ever give a form field a `name="submit"` - you REALLY need some quotes here too

Comment: Why are you starting a session there?

Comment: error in the sense if the data entered is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to check every single value :

```
$fname = isset($_POST["fname"]) ? $_POST["fname"] : '';
```

Then, in each corresponing input, add "value" attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $fname ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Store value in session

Try this code :-

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //use this code inside this if
    $_SESSION['data']=$_POST;
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION['data']);
    print "</pre>";
```

> And show value like that

```
<input type=text value="<?php echo $_SESSION['data']['fname']; ?>" name = fname placeholder=First Name />
```